# Removing submit from url with route

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to figure out how I can set up my routes so that if any of my controllers have a submit function then it does not show it in the url.

Example.

siteurl.com/cms/register/submit turns into siteurl.com/cms/register after the form submission that way it doesn't show the submit function in the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this in your route file:

```
$route['register/(:num)'] = 'register/submit/$1';
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Didn't work. Everytime I load the register controller and hit the submit button on my form it still SHOWS the submit function in the url.

Answer (score 0):

```
$route['/submit'] = 'controller/submit';
```

not tested, try this

Comment: Didn't work. Everytime I load the register controller and hit the submit button on my form it still SHOWS the submit function in the url.

Comment: well in that case, u need to modify your .htaccess file to remove it

Answer (score 0):

Override the default routes in the routes.php config file:

```
$route['cms/register'] = '/cms/register/submit';
```

in your form use the /cms/register. In this way whenever you go to /cms/register CI knows that it has to invoke the /cms/register/submit  controller method.

For more information go [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: Didn't work. Everytime I load the register controller and hit the submit button on my form it still SHOWS the submit function in the url.